# Iphone Auto fit to page

Tags: iphone, html, mobile

Is there a way to get a page to auto fit to screen on rotation of an iPhone?

When i rotate the iPhone to landscape the screen zooms in to a certain point of the page and doesnt fit the screen, therefore you have to scroll back out to view the content.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, I think you want this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

Comment: [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) advise not use semicolon as a deliminator for multiple properties: "A space may work as a deliminator but a comma is preferred."